# Newline in datatable Gherkin/Cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, testing, cucumber, gherkin

I have this datatable in my cucumber scenario:

```
| name        | value
| Description | one \n two \n three |
```

I want the values to appear in the textarea like this:

```
one
two
three
```

Because I need to make bullet points out of them.
So my actual question is, is it possible to use newline characters in one line or is there a better way to approach this?

***EDIT:*** to clarify, it's not working with the code written above:

```
WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime. evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

***EDIT 2:*** I'm using a bit of unusual code to access the value, seeing as it is a p element and this is normally not possible:

```
js.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = ' " + row.get("value") + " ' ");
```

This has been working for other rows tho, maybe because i'm using \n now?

Comment: What do you mean with 'better' way?

Comment: better/other way, just any way that would help me get the result

Comment: As is now, should work. There is no need to change the code

Comment: WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime. evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Could you please share the code you have so far?

Comment: i've edited my post with the method that reads the datatable

Comment: What returns `row.get("value")`?

Comment: whatever is in the "value" column for the corresponding "name" column

Comment: It works fine for me https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc8cP.png

Comment: maybe because you are typing it in the innerHTML itself? I tried your way '/*one\ntwo\nthree*/' . Now it's not crashing but it's not showing anything either

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786797/newline-in-datatable-gherkin-cucumber/51787544#51787544");
Thread.sleep(3000); // pause to wait until page loads

String s = "SOME<br>WORDS";

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = '" + s + "';");
```

Output:

```
SOME 
WORDS
```

---

So, main idea is to use `<br>` tag as new line separator.

In your case it would be like this:

```
| name        | value
| Description | one<br>two<br>three |
```

and code would be:

```
// make sure, that row.get("value") returns a string
js.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = ' " + row.get("value") + " ' ");
```

Comment: I have found a solution, please have a look

Comment: Sorry for the delay, was on holiday. I copied the code from above and it ignores the breaklines.